# How to create a User model in Django which contains a list of friens which are "User" models as well

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model named User and it must have a list of friends which are also "User"s.How shall i go about doing this. Should I make another model named Friends which will contain two "ForeignKey"s to the model User.Or is there any other way of doing this??

Comment: Show us your model and you have tried so far!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert Friends instance in the Profile Model. You won't need to make another model for friends . You can add in it like:-

```
def Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    default='',unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=60, default='')
    friends = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```